# node.js htm file

Tags: html, node.js, response

I got two problem

I'm quite new to node.js i worked through some tutorials .
All tutorials are talking about generating dynamic HTMl.
But isn't there a way to return a "normal" HTML file ?

Or do I have to read read it via fs and return the readed content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html). It makes this stuff easy.

If you want to render an HTML file after doing some server logic in a specific route you can always name your html file .ejs and use this.

```
res.render("normalhtml.ejs")
```

You can even tell express to make it read .ejs files as .html files.

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.register(".html", require( "ejs" ) 
res.render("normalhtml.html")
```

But you probably just want a place to put static html files. In that case use the connect-static middleware people spoke about. It's built-in to express.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Anything in the public folder will then be accessible after the / so index.html would be accessible at / or /index.html for example.

For more info see:
http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: Is express also aviable for windows ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it does or will. this bug about it NOT working on Windows might be a good place to start. https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/795

Answer (score 1):

Node doesn't provide a way to automatically serve HTTP files by itself, so yes, you would have to read the file yourself and output it. However, there are a lot of things you can do wrong and a lot of things to think of, so I would consider using a module made for **static file serving** like [Paperboy](https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy) or [Connect's static middleware](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need a static file server for that, and there are plenty. I suggest you take a look at [connect-static](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html).

Other file serving modules:

https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy 
https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static

Here is the full list:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-web-frameworks-static

Also if you'd like to have a more complete framework, along with file serving I suggest using [Express](http://expressjs.com), which has Connect under the hood.